# How do I save an object in IndexedDB?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to store my API data in indexedDB of Browser. I would have tried local storage but it has a limit of 5MB but my JSON data is more than 7MB. I want to save in indexedDB for faster access. I want to save the whole data in the JSON format but don't know how to set the scheme of the indexed DB. The data fetched from the database is testData

```
const db =new Dexie("ReactDexie");
db.version(1).stores({
            test:"++id title "   //Dont Know how to set scheme here for my json object
        })
        db.open().catch((err)=>{
            console.log(err.stack || err)
        })

        var transaction = db.transaction([testData], IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE); 
        var objstore = transaction.objectStore(testData); 

        for (var i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) { 
            objstore.put(testData[i]);
        }
```

Comment: But why are saving data more then 5 mb in browser

Comment: Hey Dheeraj, have you solved this?, or you still might need help?

Comment: not yet still looking for solution

Comment: Adding answer for how I would handle this case scenario

Comment: Where are you adding your answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow these steps for good architecture and reusable components ( Sample project is created [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-indexeddb-dexie-implementation?file=src/App.js) ):-

1 )  Create one file lets just name it `indexDB.js`

```
import Dexie from 'dexie';

const db = new Dexie('ReactDexie');

db.version(1).stores({
  testData: 'datakey'
});

export default db;
```

2 )  Now make one utility function that will store API data (let's assume this is in file `utility.js`)

```
import db from './indexDB.js';

export async function saveDataInIndexDB(data) {
  if (data) {
    if (db.testData) db.testData.clear();
    db.testData.add({ datakey: 'datakey', data }).then(() => {});
  }
}
```

3 )  function for fetching data from indexDB (in `utility.js` file)

```
export async function getDataFromIndexDB() {
  const testData = await db.testData
    .where('datakey')
    .equals('datakey')
    .toArray();
  if (testData && testData.length > 0) {
    return testData[0];
  }
  return null;
}
```

4 )  I am considering sample JSON data as following (suppose you are getting this data in `App.js`)

```
const sampleJSONdata = {
    type: 'articles',
    id: '1',
    attributes: {
      title: 'JSON:API paints my bikeshed!',
      body: 'The shortest article. Ever.',
      created: '2015-05-22T14:56:29.000Z',
      updated: '2015-05-22T14:56:28.000Z'
    }
  };
```

5 )  Store and Fetch data as following (you can call `utility.js` functions in `App.js file)

```
  saveDataInIndexDB(sampleJSONdata);

  const getDataFromDB = async () => {
    let data = await getDataFromIndexDB();
    console.log('Data ', data);
  };

  console.log(getDataFromDB());
```

The sample project is created [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-indexeddb-dexie-implementation?file=src/App.js), you can refer to this project for further use, more about schema and useful Dexie related article you can find [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/dexie-js-indexeddb-react-apps-offline-data-storage/).

Note*- Please clear site data, you might face multiple version issues as you were trying earlier (in that case you can change or add extraversion)