# Can't save values using indexedDB

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, indexeddb

Hello I am stuck with indexedDB. When I try to store an array of links, it fails with no errors or exceptions.
I have two code examples. This one works fine:

```
export const IndexedDB = {
  initDB(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onupgradeneeded = function () {
        open.result.createObjectStore("store", { keyPath: "id" });
        resolve("Database initialized successfully...");
      };
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };
      open.onsuccess = function () {
        resolve("Database initialized successfully...");
      };
    });
  },

  getAll(): Promise<Values> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };

      open.onsuccess = function () {
        const tx = open.result.transaction("store", "readonly");
        const store = tx.objectStore("store");
        const getFromStore = store.getAll();

        getFromStore.onerror = function (err) {
          reject(err);
        };

        getFromStore.onsuccess = function () {
          resolve(getFromStore.result);
        };
      };
    });
  },

  putMany(values: Values): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };

      open.onsuccess = function () {
        values.forEach((value: Value) => {
          const tx = open.result.transaction("store", "readwrite");
          const store = tx.objectStore("store");
          const putInStore = store.put(value);

          putInStore.onerror = function (err) {
            reject(err);
          };
        });
        resolve();
      };
    });
  },
};
```

App.tsx:

```
export const saveValues = (values: Values): Promise<void> => {
  IndexedDB.putMany(values);
};

export const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const valuesForTest: Values = [
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      text: "Hello world!"
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      text: "Hello world!"
    },
    {
      id: Math.random(),
      text: "Hello world!"
    }
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
        saveValuesToDB(valuesForTest);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SomeComponent/>
  );
};
```

And this one always fails. No errors or exceptions at all. The data just isn't saved.
The main difference is just data types. The first example uses the "Values" type, and the second uses the "Links" type.

```
export const IndexedDB = {
  initDB(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onupgradeneeded = function () {
        open.result.createObjectStore("store", { keyPath: "href" });
        resolve("Database initialized successfully...");
      };
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };
      open.onsuccess = function () {
        resolve("Database initialized successfully...");
      };
    });
  },

  getAll(): Promise<Links> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };

      open.onsuccess = function () {
        const tx = open.result.transaction("store", "readonly");
        const store = tx.objectStore("store");
        const getFromStore = store.getAll();

        getFromStore.onerror = function (err) {
          reject(err);
        };

        getFromStore.onsuccess = function () {
          resolve(getFromStore.result);
        };
      };
    });
  },

  putMany(values: Links): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const open = indexedDB.open("MyDB", 1);
      open.onerror = function (err) {
        reject(err);
      };

      open.onsuccess = function () {
        values.forEach((value: Link) => {
          const tx = open.result.transaction("store", "readwrite");
          const store = tx.objectStore("store");
          const putInStore = store.put(value);

          putInStore.onerror = function (err) {
            reject(err);
          };
        });
        resolve();
      };
    });
  },
};
```

App.tsx:

```
export const saveValues = (values: Links): Promise<void> => {
  IndexedDB.putMany(values);
};

export const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const valuesForTest: Links = [
    {
      href: "https://somelink1.com/",
      name: "Link"
    },
    {
      href: "https://somelink2.com/",
      name: "Link"
    },
    {
      href: "https://somelink3.com/",
      name: "Link"
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
        saveValuesToDB(valuesForTest);
  }, []);

  return (
    <SomeComponent/>
  );
};
```

Can you help me?

Comment: For starters, specify the same onupgradeneeded handler every time you open the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created the database with the first code snippets, your "store" object store will be using `id` as keyPath. If you want to change this to `href` as in your second snippet, delete the database first (in the browser devtools), then run your second snippet.

Kindly note that if you want to make schema changes to an existing database (without deleting it), you will have to pass a higher version number to indexedDB.open to trigger your `onupgradeneeded` callback: `indexedDB.open("MyDB", 2);`. If the database exists with the same version, that callback will (obviously) not be executed because it doesn't need upgrading.

Also note that if you want to use both your code snippets to store different things (values and links), use separate object stores for them: `createObjectStore("values", { keyPath: "id" })` and `createObjectStore("links", { keyPath: "href" })`

Last but not least, for easier IndexedDB usage I can really recommend to use [AceBase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/acebase) (fullblown realtime database) or [Dexie](https://dexie.org/) (simple IndexedDB wrapper) instead. Those are easy to use and handle all IndexedDB plumbing!

EDIT: In your `putMany` method I also see you call `resolve` in the `open.onsuccess` callback, instead of waiting until all of your `put` operations have succeeded. That's why you don't get an error, `reject` will be called after `resolve` so that does nothing.

Comment: For step by step guide, live example and best practices have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571586/how-do-i-save-an-object-in-indexeddb/67591834#67591834